# Bootstrp with matrices instead of vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, time-series, correlation, data-analysis, cross-correlation

I am using `xcorr` to calculate the cross-correlation between two time series. In order to assess statistical significance, I need to perform bootstrapping and create random correlations between the two time series to create a null distribution. So for instance `timeseries1` is of size 16x11 (which is 16 time points and 11 subjects) and `timeseries2` is also sized 16x11. Here the subjects are matched pairs so, for example`,` `timeseries1(:,1)` is matched to `timeseries2(:,1)`; i.e. timeseries1 is one type of data from subject one and `timeseries2(:,1)` is a different type of data from subject one.

I need to scramble them such that I create new random correlations such as `timeseries1(:,1)` with `timeseries2(:,5)` etc.

I was trying to use `boostrp` as follows

```matlab
scorr = @(timseries1,timeseries2)(xcorr(timseries1,timeseries2,'coeff'));
bootstat = bootstrp(1000,scorr,a,b);
```

However, I'm getting an error because bootstrap only accepts vectors and not matrices. In the documentation of the function, all the examples that are provided have data that is 1 value per subject so for example LSAT score from 15 subjects correlated with other test score from 15 subjects. But I have 16 samples per subject and I won't be able to do a cross-correlation if I reduce the time series to one time point.

Does anyone have any advice on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use randperm to sample without replacement, which will return two different random intergers between 1:n_subjects:

```
n_boot = 100;
n_subj = 11;
n_samples = 16;
timeseries1 = randn(n_samples, n_subj);
timeseries2 = randn(n_samples, n_subj);


null_dist = nan(n_boot,  ...
                n_samples*2-1);
for i = 1:n_boot
    
    subjs_to_corr = randperm(n_subj, 2);  % draw 2 random numbers from 1:n_subj without replacement
    
    null_dist(i, :) = xcorr(timeseries1(:, subjs_to_corr(1)),  ... 
                            timeseries2(:, subjs_to_corr(2)));
end
```